# Access parent component state from child component

Tags: reactjs

I can't figure out how to access parent component state from child component. When I try my code below I get an error in my parent components saying:

> Stateless function components cannot have refs.

Can someone point in the right direction?

**This is my parent Component (Podcast.js)**

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import PodcastItem from './PodcastItem';

class Podcast extends PureComponent { // PureComponent is preferred here instead of Component

  constructor(props) {
    super(props); 

    this.state = {
      podcast: []
    };
  }

  // Fetches podID from props.match
  fetchPodcast () {

    fetch(`https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=podcast&country=se&media=podcast&entity=podcast&limit=20`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ podcast: data.results }));
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    this.fetchPodcast()
  }

  // Check if new props is not the same as prevProps
  componentDidUpdate (prevProps) {
    // respond to parameter change
    let oldId = prevProps.match.params.podID
    let newId = this.props.match.params.podID
    if (newId !== oldId)
      this.fetchPodcast()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Country ({this.props.match.params.podID}) </h2>
        <ul>
          {this.state.podcast.map(podcast => (
            <PodcastItem key={podcast.collectionId} podcast={podcast} />
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Podcast;
```

**And this is the child component (PodcastItem.js)**

```
import React from 'react';

// Here Stateless function is enough
const PodcastItem = ({ podcast }) => (
  <li key={podcast.collectionId}>
    <a ref={podcast.collectionId}>{podcast.collectionName}</a>
  </li>
);

export default PodcastItem;
```

Comment: This error should happen whether or not you have the child component present, as the only map in the code is on the parent, mapping over its own state. My guess is that within `fetchPodcast`, the `data.results` is undefined, so `podcast` on state is being set to undefined

Comment: check the value of `data.results` here: `.then(data => {console.log(data.results); this.setState({ podcast: data.results }));`, make sure it contains the array.

Comment: I get the array. I have updated the question... I had fiddled with the code before pasting it. The problem I get is: Stateless function components cannot have refs in my parent Component. I cant access the state of podcast..

Comment: Why are you using the ref prop in your stateless component?

Comment: Thought that I should do it that way. But maybe I am wrong. Im the learning stages of ReactJS...

Comment: When to Use Refs
There are a few good use cases for refs:

Managing focus, text selection, or media playback.
Triggering imperative animations.
Integrating with third-party DOM libraries.
Avoid using refs for anything that can be done declaratively.
https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html